# Null pointer in CFRelease (told by static anylizer)

Tags: ios, xcode, clang-static-analyzer

I got this code:

```
- (void)saveImageWithData:(NSData*)jpeg andDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dicRef andName:(NSString*)name
{
    self.capturedImageName = name;
    self.dict = dicRef;

    NSLog(@"%@",dicRef);

    CGImageSourceRef  source ;
    source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)jpeg, NULL);

    CFStringRef UTI = CGImageSourceGetType(source); //this is the type of image (e.g., public.jpeg)

    NSMutableData *dest_data = [NSMutableData data];


    CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData((__bridge CFMutableDataRef)dest_data,UTI,1,NULL);

    if(!destination) {
        NSLog(@"***Could not create image destination ***");
    }

    //add the image contained in the image source to the destination, overwriting the old metadata with our modified metadata
    CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(destination,source,0, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) dicRef);

    //tell the destination to write the image data and metadata into our data object.
    //It will return false if something goes wrong
    BOOL success = NO;
    success = CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination);

    if(!success) {
        NSLog(@"***Could not create data from image destination ***");
    }

    //now we have the data ready to go, so do whatever you want with it
    //here we just write it to disk at the same path we were passed

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ARPictures"];

    NSError *error;
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]; //Create folder

    NSString *fullPath = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", name]]; //add our image to the path

    [dest_data writeToFile:fullPath atomically:YES];

    self.img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:dest_data]; 
    self.capturedImageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:dest_data];

    //cleanup

    CFRelease(destination);
    CFRelease(source);

}
```

But when I run the static analyzer it tells me that:

> Null pointer argument in call to CFRelease

But according to my logic I should be releasing the CGImageSourceRef which is created by a **CGImageDestinationCreateWithData**.

Also I am thinking that releasing it might be a mistake because i am just bridging it, which means arc still controls that object since its originally a **NSMutableData** object.

To make matters worse i read that CFRelease(Null) is not good.

I'm super confused, any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

Ok i nslogged the pointers before sending them to the CFRelease, they are there!

```
2012-03-03 11:35:34.709 programtest[4821:707] <CGImageDestination 0x331790 [0x3f92d630]>

2012-03-03 11:35:34.723 programtest[4821:707] <CGImageSource 0x33ee80 [0x3f92d630]>
```

So back to the original question, how why is the static analyzer telling me that i am sending a null pointer argument? and how do i fix/mute this?

thanks

PD: Is it possible that i am not sending a null pointer but a pointer to null?

Comment: Have you tried using nil for your arguments rather than NULL?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, the problem is that these pointes should not be nill or null, because they are sent to the CFRelease() which as i read will crash the program. I am asking about why are they becoming null if im not nulling them anywhere.

Comment: Those are C APIs, so NULL is "more correct" even if the runtime can't tell the difference between nil and NULL. nil should only be used to mean a null Objective-C object pointer. It's pedantic, yeah, but it's good style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What static analyser is telling you is that it's **possible** for one of the argumenta to be null.

For example if you place a return after

```
NSLog(@"***Could not create image destination ***");
```

Does the warning stop?

Comment: O_o this is magic, i added a return in the if(!destination) after the message u said and it gave me another warning saying that i could have a potential leak with the, so i added a CFRelease(source); before that return and all warnings went away. I didnt know the static analyzer was so smart. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

CFRelease will crash if you pass a NULL in, so the analyzer's warning you that destination and source might be NULL there. Simply add a check for NULL:

```
if ( destination != NULL )
    CFRelease(destination);

if ( source != NULL )
    CFRelease(source);
```